# Filter on inner object in Elasticsearch returns 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I run the following query on Elasticsearch 1.5, constructed with elasticsearch-dsl in python, and it returns 0 results. I do the same search using Kabana, and I get more than 1000 results. What am I doing wrong?

`(Search().using(es).index('inventory')
    .filter('term', identifiers__autodata='CAC70FOS132A0'))`

which results in

```

```
{
   'query':{
      'filtered':{
         'query':{
            'match_all':{}
         },
         'filter':{
            'term':{
               'identifiers.autodata':'CAC70FOS132A0'
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```